# Testing if a value was entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input, calculator

I wrote a calculator, I want to be able to enter two numbers or three.
currently this is what I have:

```
def main():
    action2=0
    user_input=input("Enter a num1 act1 num2 act2 num3 (with a space between them): ")      #Gets the values
    var1, action1, var2, action2, var3=user_input.split()   #assigns the values into the variables
    if(action2==0):
        calc2(float(var1), action1, float(var2))
    else:
        calc3(float(var1), action1, float(var2), action2, float(var3))
```

How do I make it work?
It gives me an error that I need 5 variables for the *split()* action, which makes sense. My question is what can I do (what way) can I do what I want?

Full code:

```
def calculate(num1, num2, act):
    if(act=='+'):
        total=num1+num2
    elif(act=='-'):
        total=num1-num2
    elif(act=='*'):
        total=num1*num2
    elif(act=='/'):
        total=num1/num2
    else:
        print("input not recognized")
    return total

def calc2(var1, action1, var2):
    if(action1=='/' and var2==0):      #checks for division by 0
        print("YOU CAN'T DIVIDE BY ZERO!!!")
    else:
        print(calculate(float(var1), float(var2), action))     #calls the 'calculating' function, recives and prints the total of act

def main():
    action2=0        #testing if anything was entered as action2
    user_input=input("Enter a num1 act1 num2 act2 num3 (with a space between them): ")      #Gets the values
    var1, action1, var2, action2, var3=user_input.split()   #assigns the values into the variables
    if(action2==0):   #two num calc
        calc2(float(var1), action1, float(var2))
    else:    #three num calc
        calc3(float(var1), action1, float(var2), action2, float(var3))

def calc3(var1, action1, var2, action2, var3):
    if(action1=='/' and var2==0 or action2=='/' and var3==0):      #checks for division by 0
        print("YOU CAN'T DIVIDE BY ZERO!!!")
    elif((action2=='*' or action2=='/') and (action1=='+' or action2=='-')):    #checks if act2 should be done before act1 (order of operation) total=calculate(float(var2), float(var3), action2)     #calls the 'calculating' function, recives the total of act2
        total=calculate(float(var2), float(var3), action2)
        print(calculate(float(var1), float(total), action1))     #calls the 'calculating' function, assigns the total of act2 as num2, recives and prints the total of act1
    else:                                                             #act1 is done before act2 (order of operation)
        total=calculate(float(var1), float(var2), action1)         #calls the 'calculating' function, recives the total of act1
        print(calculate(float(total), float(var3), action2))     #calls the 'calculating' function, assigns the total of act1 as num1, recives and prints the total of act2



main()           #starts program
```

Comment: You're trying to assign five variables to the result of the split. If there are not five things in the return value, you have written an error. You could capture the return value in one list instead of a bunch of variables. `parts = user_input.split()`. Then you can check `if len(parts)==5: ...` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unpacking five values, you must *actually have* 5 values.  You cannot unpack 3 values into 5 variables.  Change you code to check how many inputs were received before unpacking.

```
user_input=input("Enter a an expression (with a space between tokens): ")
inputs_amt = len(user_input.split())
if inputs_amt == 5:
  var1, action1, var2, action2, var3 = user_input.split() 
elif inputs_amt == 3:
  var1, action1, var2 = user_input.split()
else:
  print "Invalid input, try again"
```

You will also have to rewrite the calculation code to account for this difference.

**EDIT:**

`user_input.split()` produces a list of strings.  If you unpack this list like this:

```
var1, action1, var2, action2, var3 = user_input.split()
```

Then there *must be* five elements (numbers or operators) in the list, because it's being unpacked into five variables.  If there is any other amount of elements, it will throw an error.

So, you must check how many elements will result from `split()` before you unpack it.  You also could just skip the unpacking and iterate over the list, keeping a running total.

```
total = 0
op = "+"
for foo in user_input.split():
  if foo.isdigit():
    if op == "+":
      total += int(foo)
    if op == "-":
      total -= int(foo)
    if op == "*":
      total *= int(foo)
    if op == "/":
      total /= int(foo)
  else:
    op = foo

print(total)
```

**EXTRA**: Your strategy for evaluating an expression fails to account for operator precedence, and will require extra code for longer (or shorter) expressions.  [See here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#Python) for a more complex, but more robust arithmetic expression resolver.

Comment: @Sela12 edited for more explanation.  Hope this helps :)